# Correct way of carrying out a T-Test between two populations, each with several measurements with individual standard deviations?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am carrying out method A and method B on a process. The efficiency of the method can be measured with quantity Alpha. After employing each method, several measurements on Alpha are done.

In the end we have for each population (A and B) several measurements, each with its own standard deviation.

What would be the right way to carry out a T-test between both populations (with the hypothesis being that both populations are different) taking into account the standard deviations of each measurement?

My approach so far is to find the combined deviations of each population by employing

$
SD_{A} = \sqrt{SD^{2}_{A1}+ SD^{2}_{A2} + ... + SD^{2}_{AN}}
$

Where N is the total amount of measurements. Do this for both populations and carry out a T-test between them.

However I feel this is not completely right.

EDIT: extra information - data looks something like this (not exact values)

Method A:

- A1 - Measurements of Alpha = {7, 8.1, 7.8, 8.2, 8.5}
- A2 - Measurements of Alpha = {8.1, 8.4, 7.9, 8.6, 8.8, 9.2}
- A3 - Measurements of Alpha = {6.9, 7.5, 7.8, 7.2}

... until $A_{N}$

Method B:

- B1 - Measurements of Alpha = {8.3, 8.7, 9.8, 9.2, 9.5, 8.7, 8.8}
- B2 - Measurements of Alpha = {9.1, 8.6, 9.2, 8.7, 8.7, 9.3}
- B3 - Measurements of Alpha = {7.9, 8.2, 7.3, 8.2, 7.9}

... until $B_{M}$

Notes, each set of measurements has a different number of elements, and N is usually equal to M, but not necessarily

Comment: What is alpha ? how is it computed

Comment: By measurements, do you means samples? Also, are these samples independent of each other?

Comment: @subhashc.davar it is a direct measurement of a physical property.

Comment: @Arun Jose, yes I mean samples. They are independent of each other.

Comment: Can't you then just take all sample of process A as a single sample?

Comment: @ArunJose yes, that would be my last approach. Each process (either method) takes a lot of time and given other constraints (cooperation with several other colleagues) it is easier to handle each process as a single measurement with its own SD. However you are absolutely right, the easiest solution is just to take all single measurements and analyze them together.

Comment: Please indicate how do you compute SD square for A -1 etc . What is the sample-size for each - A1 and  A 2 etc . More-over,  do you have  alpha values for  each  observation? if you can paste a sample part  of your data, this will help me understand your problem.

Comment: Good edit. A query ! confused about population and the term method. You seem to be interested in checking whether adoption of  method A vis a vis Method B makes  a substantive  difference in Alpha on an average ?

Comment: @subhashc.davar exactly. I have decided to just include all measurements in a single pooled sample. Thank you for your responses

Comment: I shall appreciate if you could respond to my comment adequately. Unless and until, I have more details, I cannot say anything about what you are doing ? and whether it is correct or incorrect?

Comment: Please consider removing tag probability and statistical significance and add t-statistic in your title part of the question .